# "Unexpected error determining execution environment" when running Firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Everything works correctly when I deploy my functions, but running the same code locally with the Firebase emulator gives me the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Unexpected error determining execution environment: request to http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance failed, reason: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.1.101:56456)",
  "type": "system",
  "errno": "EHOSTDOWN",
  "code": "EHOSTDOWN",
  "config": {
    "url": "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance",
    "headers": {
      "Metadata-Flavor": "Google"
    },
    "retryConfig": {
      "noResponseRetries": 0,
      "currentRetryAttempt": 0,
      "retry": 3,
      "retryDelay": 100,
      "httpMethodsToRetry": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD",
        "PUT",
        "OPTIONS",
        "DELETE"
      ],
      "statusCodesToRetry": [
        [
          100,
          199
        ],
        [
          429,
          429
        ],
        [
          500,
          599
        ]
      ]
    },
    "responseType": "text",
    "timeout": 3000,
    "params": {},
    "method": "GET"
  }
}
```

What should I do to be able to test my code with the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

If your cloud function requires admin rights, then you need to configure a service account for the cloud functions to run under.

Follow the instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

#### The mains steps are:

1) Create a Service Account and download the .json private key files (keep this secret)

**In the console where you will run your emulator:**

2) Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the **absolute** path of the private key file saved in step 1. For example `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/..../...account.json"`

3) Now run your emulator `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

Now the locally emulated function knows the environment. So when you do something like `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` it gets configured properly.