# Why firebase requests don't work on firebase serve?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, postman

Whenever i try to make a request by using firebase serve it fails.  Everything works correctly when I firebase deploy my functions and then make request, but running same functions locally by firebase serve doesn't work. I'm using Postman to make requests.

My steps: I run firebase serve in cmd in the folder with my functions. Then I copy the link that i get in response and paste it to Postman and then i run the request with this link e.g http://localhost:5000/workers-7baca/us-central1/api/workers. Postman gives me no response and i get error in the console.

The code of my function:

```
app.get("/workers", (req, res) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("workers")
    .get()
    .then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

The same code works for me when i do request from deployment link but it doesnt work on localhost.

Im getting network timeout error like `FetchError: Unexpected error determining execution environment: network timeout`.

What is the problem?

EDIT: I Found a working solution for me there https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/344

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly the steps you go through to test your function.  Anyone should be able to reproduce the problem by following those steps.

Comment: I have changed my description of the problem and added the steps. Thanks for advice

Comment: What exactly is giving that message?  Postman?  Or is it output from `firebase serve`?  What is the code of your function?

Comment: Postman's message is "Could not get any response. There was an error connecting to."  And acutally there are no errors from firebase serve, the only error I get is from my catch. I added code to main post

Comment: If there is a problem with the emulator, then you should post your full reproduction steps to the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I just found a solution there https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/344
It's a bug which you can workaround

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error when try runs locally functions from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936431/how-to-fix-error-when-try-runs-locally-functions-from-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
2. Click “Create service account”, give it a name (e.g. emulator), give it the Project>Owner role. Check “Furnish a new private key”, pick “JSON”.
3. Save the file somewhere on your computer
4. Run
   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=”absolute/path/to/file.json”
5. Run
   firebase serve --only functions

Answer (score 0):

Install the firebase emulators

```
firebase emulators:start
```

and use the local servers generated to connect to database